# How to get last inserted attribute option Id?

Tags: attributes, magento-1.8, eav, dropdown-attribute

I use the following code to add an option to my "dropdown attribute":

```
public function createAttributeOption($option){
    $arg_attribute = 'attribute_code';
    $arg_value = $option;

    $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
    $attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();

    $option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
    $option['value']['any_option_name'][0] = $arg_value;

    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
    return '???';
}
```

and that perfectly inserts the option to my attribute.
The question is I need to return the inserted option's ID from this function. How can I get the id of this last inserted option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$lastId = $setup->getConnection()->lastInsertId();
$attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setStoreFilter()
            ->addFieldToFilter('tsv.value_id',array('eq'=>$lastId))
            ->getFirstItem();

$optionId = $attr->getData('option_id');
return $optionId;
```

Comment: that gives me the "value_id" from `eav_attribute_option_value` table, but i need "option_id", which model i can use to get option_id from the value_id I get?

Comment: @Shathish. Instead of editing my answer you should add your complete answer.

Comment: okay, I thought it would become an additional answer and it wud be better to have a single answer. I'll post my answers separately here afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $order->getId();
echo $lastInsertId  = $db_write ->fetchOne('SELECT last_insert_id()');
echo $db_write ->lastInsertId(); // you may also try this.
```

You can get all info regarding Last insert id 
[Click Here](http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/get-last-insert-id-in-magento.html)